# Dynamic URLs in Typescript

Tags: asp.net, typescript

I have a web app built using asp.net core, vue.js and typescript. My Typescript code needs to fetch data from an API as follows:

```
var myFetch = fetch(this.apiurl + '/apipath', {
        cache: 'no-cache',
        method: 'GET'
    })
```

But I need the URL for the API (this.apiurl) to be configurable instead of hard-coding. The URL will be different for each deployment, and can be on different domains i.e. myapp.clientdomain.com, myapp.otherdomain.com.

Can anyone provide an example of providing a URL dynamically to Typescript so it uses my configured URL instead of a hard-coded one? I have looked at:

1. MVC providing a JavaScript response (seems overly complex for what I need - just one variable to be set dynamically...)
2. Creating an API within the .net core web app that returns URLs via a fetch, then calls the actual APIs (URL has to fetch-ed at run-time before subsequent calls to get data, resulting in longer load times)
3. Building/packaging with a separate URL Typescript file depending on the client (not configurable without a recompile)

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: This isn't really specific to TypeScript, and is probably a bit too broad for SO, but I would say you're on the right track with (2). You can call the configuration API early and once so there isn't noticeable difference in subsequent API calls.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron - I'll see if I can hook that up then, I've got plenty of code already was just checking if there was a better way. The TypeScript complexity I have is around the fact TypeScript is compiled, trying to inject values in dynamically is the challenge that I am stuck on. There are plenty of examples of putting in Dev/Test/Production values based on environment, but I can't seem to find a way to have custom values put in unless it's at design time. All I really wanted was something like "myUrl1: string = [dynamic value]" but the config API might be the best way.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. You can inject variables at build time, they just need to be valid JS variables (ie valid JS syntax before replacement) and then you can use for example `declare const _DEV_: boolean` so TypeScript knows about it.